# Add traces and exceptions to Prometheus using OpenTelemetry in .NET 6

Tags: prometheus, .net-6.0, trace, webapi, open-telemetry

I have configured OpenTelemetry in my Startup.cs class in a Web API project to export metrics to a Prometheus exported. I have been successful in doing so using the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .WithMetrics(b => b
                .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddPrometheusExporter());
}
```

Now I want support for exceptions since I also want to log exceptions in Prometheus. I am unable to find a way to do so. I was hoping there was a WithExceptions method just like WithMetrics which is not available.

Additionally, I want to add custom traces as well and I see there is a WithTraces method in OpenTelemetryBuilder class. However, I don't see any Prometheus Exporter. Instead, there is only a ConsoleExporter. I am unable to find a way to export the traces to Prometheus.

I tried finding a solution for this issue but the ones I found were related to .NET Core, not .NET 6. Additionally, I am unable to find anything related to what I want to achieve in the OpenTelemetry documentation as well.

This is what I have modified so far to add support for traces:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .WithMetrics(b => b
                .AddRuntimeInstrumentation()
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddPrometheusExporter())
            .WithTracing(b => b
                .AddSource("MySource")
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
                .AddConsoleExporter());
}
```

For reference, these are the libraries and their versions that I am using:

```
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Console" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OpenTelemetryProtocol" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Prometheus.AspNetCore" Version="1.5.1-beta.1" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.RunTime" Version="1.5.1" />
```

Comment: I think you're confusing traces and metrics here, traces don't go in Prometheus as it's a metrics solution. You could maybe think about a metric for exception information, but it's not usually something that you use metrics for.

Comment: For traces (which will include exceptions), you need a different style of backend, for opensource look at Jaeger

Comment: Prometheus collects metrics, not traces. It simply can't read them. `only a ConsoleExporter` on the contrary there are Jaeger, Zipkin and other third-party exporters. The OtlpExporter can be used with most monitoring tools too. In fact, Jaeger suggest using the OTLP exporter instead of the Jaeger exporter